# proxy Services in WSO2

Tags: web-services, proxy, wso2-esb

How to develope a web service in WSO2 using proxy services ?

Applying my Oracle Service Bus knowledge here to create a proxy service which would take a string as an Input and return the same as response, I find it difficult in WSO2 to create a proxy service using my XML Schema.

I found that we can do the same in WSO2 using Custom proxy template. 
But I am not sure of defining an Input and output in proxy service ; 
In a traditional Oracle Service Bus we can do it by defining our XMl Schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need some echo kind of a service. This kind of behavior can be achieved by configuring the wso2 esb as in following manner. However this is not really a web service. I hope you are aware of what is web service and what does a proxy service does. But for your requirement you can try something like follows.

```
 <proxy name="loopBackProxy" startonload="true" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="https,http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <target>
      <insequence>
         <log level="full"></log>
         <header action="remove" name="To"></header>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"></property>
         <!-- your esb modifications here -->
         <send></send>
      </insequence>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

This doesnot contains a outsequence, what this does is redirects the input to the client.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick response ..I have created proxy using the above mentioned code and its working fine ,. I could see the response as the request that i pass. But when i try to test the service from WSO2 management console i could see the empty SOAP request , It is like  <body/> ..I guess this is because as there are no operations exposed by the service..

Comment: Could you please let me know the way to create a simple proxy service which should ask the client to pass th input ..lets say two integers and the proxy should be able to add the two integers and give the response back to the client. In Oracle Service Bus we can define our xml schema in which an xml elements like element1 type int and element2 type int will be the input and similarly an xml element named "response" of type int will be the output , in this way i can easily create a proxy service to perform the addition of two integers but i feel difficult to do the same in WSO2

Comment: @user3243890 For that, you need to create a WSDL, and modify the proxy to point to that WSDL. If the inputs to your proxy is same as the back-end web service, then you can simply point to that. Otherwise, Take the WSDL as the starting point, and modify the inputs/outputs accordingly.